# Dijkstra's Algorithm Same Node Added Multiple Times to Priority Queue

Tags: priority-queues, dijkstras-algorithm

In the [this discussion](https://bradfieldcs.com/algos/graphs/dijkstras-algorithm/) of Dijkstra's Algorithm appear the following comments:

```
# Nodes can get added to the priority queue multiple times. We only
# process a vertex the first time we remove it from the priority queue.
```

I'm curious as to under which circumstances a node would be added to the priority queue multiple times. My understanding was that once a node had been processed, it's min-distance was determined and we could forget about it.

Here's the full code for reference:

```
import heapq


def calculate_distances(graph, starting_vertex):
    distances = {vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in graph}
    distances[starting_vertex] = 0

    pq = [(0, starting_vertex)]
    while len(pq) > 0:
        current_distance, current_vertex = heapq.heappop(pq)

        # Nodes can get added to the priority queue multiple times. We only
        # process a vertex the first time we remove it from the priority queue.
        if current_distance > distances[current_vertex]:
            continue

        for neighbor, weight in graph[current_vertex].items():
            distance = current_distance + weight

            # Only consider this new path if it's better than any path we've
            # already found.
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                heapq.heappush(pq, (distance, neighbor))

    return distances


example_graph = {
    'U': {'V': 2, 'W': 5, 'X': 1},
    'V': {'U': 2, 'X': 2, 'W': 3},
    'W': {'V': 3, 'U': 5, 'X': 3, 'Y': 1, 'Z': 5},
    'X': {'U': 1, 'V': 2, 'W': 3, 'Y': 1},
    'Y': {'X': 1, 'W': 1, 'Z': 1},
    'Z': {'W': 5, 'Y': 1},
}
print(calculate_distances(example_graph, 'X'))
# => {'U': 1, 'W': 2, 'V': 2, 'Y': 1, 'X': 0, 'Z': 2}
```

Comment: Nobody really reads the full code here (on CS SE), so I would advise you to either not include the code at all, or include the *relevant* **pseudocode** (algorithm) when necessary.

Comment: By the way, I love to see the Python code. It is not unreasonable to believe Python code is better than pseudocode sometimes. Or most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what will happen for the following graph.

```
 counterexample_graph = {
    'U': {'V': 6, 'W': 7},
    'V': {'X': 10},
    'W': {'X': 1},
 }
```

[image: Counter example for cs144501, Dijkstra's Algorithm Same Node Added Multiple Times to Priority Queue]

Suppose `U` is the starting vertex. You can check that vertex `X` is added to the priority queue

1. by route `U -> V -> X`, yielding a distance of 16,
2. then by route `U -> W -> X`, yielding a shorter distance of 8.